# JIBX MAVEN Problem

Tags: java, maven-2, jibx

I am trying to use JIBX maven plugin in my Spring Web Service project,
   My project has diferent layers (API-DAO-SERVICE  vsvs..)
   these layers are individual projects and has maven dependency each other.
   In my WEB project's POM, I add other project as dependencies, and my mapping
    classes are all in API project.
   Even in my web project's POM includes dependencies of API project I could
   not use that class'es in JIBX
   BUT IF I put that class'es in WEB project's src/main/java directory there is
   NO PROBLEM,
   How can I use mapping classes  that are other maven dependent projects.
   Any help is really appreciated;
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generated sources are supposed to be compiled and packaged in the artifact at the end. The classes should thus be visible from your webapp.

Did you setup the maven-jixb-plugin as shown in [Generate Java Sources from Schemas](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/schema-codegen.html)? If not, then maybe update your setup first and try again.

And if you are still facing problems, please show the relevant parts of your POM(s).